# Invest in stock market around the world

Tags: stock-market, financial-markets

Hi i like to invest in the stock market around the world does

- it require to have a citizenship in that country
- is there any specific amount to invest in it with a deadlock period
- how can i track my investment around the globe with a single software/app
- As the global economic growth is moving into Asian market **BRICKS**

hope have raised some interesting topics